# What is the Name of the Property which Makes this True?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

sorry for the lame title.

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space and $\Omega$ a subset of $X$.
It is **not** true in general that, given $O \in T \setminus\{\varnothing\}$, we have the implication $$\Omega \cap O \neq\varnothing \implies \text{int}(\Omega \cap O) \neq\varnothing.$$

However, there is a quite familiar case in which this is apparently true: the case where $(X,T)$ is the real numbers with the usual topology and $\Omega$ is a non-trivial closed interval. **What is the property that makes it true in this case?**

At first I though maybe we need $\Omega$ to be connected and have non-empty interior, but apparently that's not enough (the counterexmaple is suggested by [user N-S](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9176/n-s): $O$ a disk in the plane and $\Omega$ a non-touching disk with the added appendage a line segment sticking out of it that pokes into $O$) I'm afraid my knowledge of Topology is still kind of infantile, so I don't have the vocabulary, and I still can't always infer from incomplete information...

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true whenever $\Omega\subseteq\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}\Omega$. In that case $O\cap\Omega\ne\varnothing$ implies that $O\cap\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}\Omega\ne\varnothing$, which in turn implies that $O\cap\operatorname{int}\Omega\ne\varnothing$. This rules out the example of the disk with a spike, because the closure of its interior is just the closed disk.

Comment: I see, and so the flood gates are opened! Just from googling cl(int(A))=A, I see that this is referred by saying that A is *regular closed,* now I must only wonder when is that the case. Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasWinckelman: You’re welcome!